# About UnboundLocalError: local variable 'font_size' referenced before assignment in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I just run this following code and hope to get the `font_size` outside the `with` command but get this error:

```
def text_image(text_path, font_path = None):

     with open(text_path, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as text_file:
         for num, data in enumerate(text_file, 1):
             lookup4font_size = 'Font-size:'

              if lookup4font_size in data:
                 font_size = next(text_file)
     print(font_size)
```

and I get this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'font_size' referenced before assignment
```

Does anyone can help me fix this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you need `return font_size`? This will end the function, aka `print(font_size)` will never be run. Either `print(font_size)` is actually `print(text_image(args))` or `return font_size` should be deleted.

Comment: Sorry I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your loop *doesn't* find what it's looking for, it ends and tries to `print(font_size)`. But it only *sets* `font_size` if it *does* find what it's looking for (and then `return`s, so the `print` is never reached in the cases where `font_size` exists). Remove the `print`; it's definitionally never going to be possible for it to succeed.

Comment: @Q.H.Chu: The edit doesn't change much. If your loop never finds the data it's looking for, it never assigns to `font_size`, so when it ends, attempts to use `font_size` fail. You could assign it a default value before the loop begins so if the loop fails, you don't try to read an uninitialized value, or you could figure out why your data file doesn't have the line(s) you seem to expect, but the fundamental problem is trying to read from a variable that has *never* been assigned to during that call of the function.

Comment: Thank you very much @ShadowRanger I have finally fix it. Like what you have said because I never declare a value before a loop so this error has occurred. Thank you so much